# Python, how to create a zip of a directory while excluding hidden files?

Tags: python, zip

I have a situation where I want to create a zip of a directory while excluding all hidden files when doing this.

Specifics of my use case: I have a directory that contains a small static site build, but also contains `.git/` and other hidden files that are very large. When I create a zip without ignoring the hidden files, the zip ends up being large (GBs), when the site itself is <5MB.

What's an efficient way to create the zip while ignoring these hidden files?

Comment: zip utilities typically have an "exclude" flag. How they work may differ between utility and OS.

Comment: _What's an efficient way to create the zip_ We would need to see how you're doing it now, to answer that question.

Comment: @tdelaney this is what Google's AI generated answer said also, however, I did not find any API (e.g., `shutil.make_archive`) that actually listed this argument.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I was using `shutil.make_archive`. I did not yet have a solution for excluding files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution. It works using `glob` and `zipfile`, both modules that are part Python's standard libraries. The crux of it is `glob('*')`, which lists only files that don't start with `.`.

```
from glob import glob
import zipfile

def zip_dir(directory, name) -> str:
    """Compress a directory into a zip. (Ignoring hidden files.)

    Args:
        directory: The directory to make into a .zip
        name: The name of the resulting .zip

    Returns:
        The name of the .zip
    """
    with zipfile.ZipFile(f"{name}.zip", 'w') as f:
        for file in glob(f"{directory}/*"):
            f.write(file)
    return name + ".zip"
```

Comment: A good answer should explain *why* it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. I've updated it.